# List doesn't get populated in the for loop

Tags: apex, loop, debug

Whole of my code works perfectly, except for this part Inside of the for loop, where the system.debugs are, the system debugs don't leave any type of message on the debug log.

The "anorder.id" comes up with a number on a debug log but the orderIDSForZCustomerCreation doesn't get populated with that number. Does anyone know why this list wouldn't get populated ?

Thanks for any information.

```
List<Id> orderIDSForZCustomerCreation = new List<Id> ();
for(Order anOrder : Trigger.new){
    System.debug('Account ID of an account in iteration: ');
    System.debug(anOrder.AccountId);
    System.debug('Order Status set and anorder.status');
    System.debug(orderStatusSet);
    System.debug(anOrder.Status);
    System.debug('Is Trigger Update: ');
    System.debug(Trigger.isUpdate);
    System.debug('Old Map: ');
    System.debug(Trigger.oldMap.get(anOrder.id).Status);
    System.debug('Acc ID:');
    System.debug(eligibleAccounts.get(anOrder.AccountId));
    System.debug('Order ID: ');
    System.debug(anOrder.Id);

    if( Trigger.isUpdate && ( orderStatusSet.contains(anOrder.Status) ) 
        && ( orderStatusSet.contains(Trigger.oldMap.get(anOrder.id).Status) == false) ){
        if( null != eligibleAccounts.get(anOrder.AccountId) ){
            orderIDSForZCustomerCreation.add(anOrder.Id);
            System.debug('Size of orderIDS inside a loop');     
            System.debug(orderIDSForZCustomerCreation.size());
        }
    }
}        

System.debug(orderIDSForZCustomerCreation.isEmpty());
System.debug(orderIDSForZCustomerCreation);
if( !orderIDSForZCustomerCreation.isEmpty() ){
    // Call SF-Zuora Synch Processos
    System.debug('Its not empty'); 
    SFZSync_ZuoraCustomerSynchProcessor.processZCustomerAccountandSubscription(orderIDSForZCustomerCreation);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting debug stmt before 'if( null != eligibleAccounts.get(anOrder.AccountId) )'

Comment: yes, I've added all of the system debug statements that I worked with and they are all coming up with values except for the latter ones inside of the if statement.

Comment: So the line: System.debug(orderIDSForZCustomerCreation.size()); prints you a size > 0?

Comment: That one doesn't get printed at all in the debug statement

Comment: Yes but than if( Trigger.isUpdate && ( orderStatusSet.contains(

anOrder.Status) ) 
                        && ( orderStatusSet.contains(Trigger.oldMap.get(anOrder.id).Status) == false) or if( null != eligibleAccounts.get(anOrder.AccountId) ) is not true and therefore, no id will be added to the list.

Comment: So basically it looks like your `if` statement is never evaluating to `true`. Have you looked at your incoming data and carefully validated it against those conditions? `orderStatusSet` must contain the new value for `Status` and not the old value, and `eligibleAccounts` must contain the key `anOrder.AccountId`.

Comment: I've attached a dubug log and even when updating the order so going from an old map to a new map it doesn't get through the if statements, I'll have a look at the data again and see if I can spot why it wouldn't go through the if statements

Comment: Your debug log clearly shows that the order status is "In Progress" with old value `null`, and `orderStatusSet` contains only "Provisioning Queue".  The `if` statement will be `false`.